# Change edge connection point with vis.js

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I have a vis.js Network diagram for a workflow visualisation. Therefore I enabled the hierarical layout (direction: LR, nodes.shape: box). Now the problem is that the edges connect at the top and bottom of the nodes and not at the right and left of the nodes. So I can't see the edges text. Is there any solution to choose where the edges connect to the nodes?

Comment: Please add some code to help us better answer your question.

Comment: Did you get a solution for your question ?